# Is Unity a DE, a WM or a Desktop shell

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is 'Ubuntu Unity' (for the Desktop)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10031/what-is-ubuntu-unity-for-the-desktop)

People seem confused about what Unity actually is. Can you please clarify if it is a desktop environment (DE), Window Manager (WM) or just a shell.

Thanks
-ActionParsnip (irc)
- Shadoweater120880 (youtube)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not confused at all. It is a **User Interface = UI**. See this question:

[Previously asked question - what is unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10031/what-is-ubuntu-unity-for-the-desktop)

and this link extracted from answer to the earlier question:

[early Launchpad blueprint for Unity](https://blueprints.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-desktop-n-specialized-unity-form-factor)

Regards.

Comment: Moron thinks Unity is a DE which is incorrect